# Google Dfp (Doubleclick For Publishers) for UWA (Windows 10)

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10, google-dfp

I'm working on a Universal Windows Application (UWP / Windows 10) and need to integrate Doubleclick For Publishers (Dfp), but not getting very far.

I've looked at the the [open source libraries on github](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dotnet-lib) to try and see if I could re-build the required dlls as a universal application library, but it seems many of the libraries/dependencies used are not available when targeting the UWP target.

How can I integrate Dfp into a Windows 10 app?

Comment: Unsure why question was marked down, would have been helpful if the person who marked down commented to explain why.  Edited it to make question clear.

Comment: Hi @Peter, I didn't down vote you. About your question, sounds like your dependencies need some API which the target doesn't support. You probably need to migrate the code, then this will be a very broad question/questions. guess that's probably the reason you get a down vote. PS The github link is dead.

Comment: Thanks @terry. I do appreciate your explanation and link has been corrected. :) I've looked to migrate the code and it seems to be a lot of work, esp when targeting the UWA the libraries are not as vast as normal. :(

Comment: If you haven't already, you should comment on [this issue](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dotnet-lib/issues/51) which I filed back in August due to the same requirement of my client.

I'm told some UWP devs have done this by putting a webview in a user control and utilizing the REST API for the calls to get the ads. I've not yet built this or seen it made in to a reusable component, unfortunately.

Comment: @bc3tech I'll reply there too, but the solution we've implemented until support is available is to use the [simplifed url tags](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/2623168?hl=en) being aware to have "co=1" in the url is for Non-JS clients i.e. email app, Windows app, etc. for the clickUrl to work on-launch.

It's not ideal, but we build the link and relevant image, then that gets programatically added to the control when it has been loaded.

Comment: Would you be willing to share your code?

Comment: @bc3tech.  I'll share what I can, but I can copy and paste the code in. Sorry. 
So we add the `Image` object to the xaml grid. Then set the source to that image with the contructed advert image url, and wrap it with the constructed  advert link url.

We construct the [simplied url & link] (https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/2623168?hl=en) 

`http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad`

Comment: arrrgggh. Sorry. Pressed enter and then could edit it fully.

with using 
<pre>
`string baseUrl = "http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad";

\\ pars.lu (below) is networkId/adunit/adtargetingpath (if you have them)

var querystring = $"co=1&iu=/{pars.Iu}&sz={pars.Dimensions}&c={pars.CacheSerial}&t={customTargeting}";

var requestUrl = $"{baseUrl}/ad?{querystring}";

var clickUrl = $"{baseUrl}/jump?{querystring}";`
</pre>